# Oracle permission granting SQl Plus

Tags: oracle, permissions, sqlplus

I am new to this stuff.. Can someone tell me how can I see granted permission for particular package and its synonym in SQL Plus and if I want to grant excute permission to particular package and synonym what I have to do.. I just wanna grant execute permission to ex_test_role Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.grantee
FROM
    dba_tab_privs p
WHERE
    p.privilege = 'EXECUTE'
    AND
    p.owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
    AND
    p.table_name IN ( 'PACKAGE_NAME', 'SYNONYM_NAME' )
```

Comment: The synonym is irrelevant. When you grant to a synonym, the grant is recorded against the underlying object (ie synonym resolved at the time of the grant).

Answer (score 0):

To do a grant on the package:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON package-name TO ex_test_role;
```

To see the existing grants:

```
SELECT *
FROM   USER_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = package-name;
```

Comment: thanx dude.. but how can i view already granted permission on certain package